# (MFC) Split a view into two side-by-side duplicates

Tags: c++, mfc, cview

I have successfully implemented view switching in a program I'm working on. My first view is a normal view displaying the document, but I want my second view to be a split view, displaying the same document, one above the other, each with their own scroll bar.

How do I approach this?

Comment: In the split view, do you want two of the same kind of view, just with (potentially) different positions, or do you want two different types of views of the same data (e.g., top view vs. side view in a graphics program?)

Comment: @JerryCoffin  I'm going for two views of the same data. One view just displays the data normally, but when you switch views, the second view will be a split screen view of the data: Two copies one on top of the other, each independently scrolling